# Loading an image from bytes in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, byte, nsimage

I'm working with an existing code base that accepts bytes from a loaded jpeg file and creates a UIImage object. That works fine on iphone but macOS needs a different implementation from what I've understood.

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:data length:length]];
if (image)
{

}
```

What is the equivalent of this on macOS? is it NsImage? How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:data length:length]];
if (image)
{

}
```